# Color the polygons in PolyhedronData

Tags: color, geometry, polyhedra

What is the simplest method for coloring each polygon face of a polyhedron with a specified color?  For instance suppose I have a list of $12$ colors (`{ Red, Green, ... }`) I would like to apply to the different faces of a `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]` in some assigned order and keep the entity as a `Dodecahedron`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
faces = First@Normal@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"];
colors = Table[ColorData[97, i], {i, 12}];
Graphics3D@Riffle[colors, faces]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yep... short and sweet.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 7):

You can get the polygons directly using the property `"Polygons"`:

```
polygons = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Polygons"];
colors = ColorData[97]/@Range[12];

Graphics3D[Transpose[{colors, polygons}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works, but could be improved:

```
myVertices = N@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"];
myFaceIndices = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"];
mycolors = {Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Orange, Black, White, 
   Purple, Green, Red, Yellow};
Graphics3D@
 Transpose[{mycolors, (Polygon[myVertices[[#]]] & /@ myFaceIndices)}]
```